# Mapping in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapping

I am new to Spark and Scala and to this kind of programming in general.

What I want to accomplish is the following:

I have an RDD that is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD**[(Double, Iterable[String])]**

So the possible content could be:

```
<1 , (A,B,C)>
<42, (A)    >
<0 , (C,D)  >
```

I need to transform this to a new RDD in such way so I get a similar output to:

```
<1, A>
<1, B>
<1, C>
<42, A>
<0, C>
<0, D>
```

This has to be very simple, but I tried so many different ways and couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMapValues`:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val r : RDD[(Double, Iterable[String])] = ...
r.flatMapValues(x => x)
```

Comment: I got an error: "missing parameter type for expanded function"
However, simply replacing (_) with (x=>x) did the job!
so:
val A = B.flatMapValues(x =>x)

Comment: @zsxwing It's not a type inference problem - `x => x` still requires type inference to work. It's just that `_` in that particular context doesn't mean the identity function.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets have the input like**

`(Name , List[Interest])`,

```
"Chandru",("Java","Scala","Python")
"Sriram", ("Science","Maths","Hadoop","C2","c3")
"Jai",("Flink","Scala","Haskell")
```

> Create a case class for the person,

```
 case class Person(name:String, interest:List[String])
```

> Create input

```
 val input={Seq(Person("Chandru",List("Java","Scala","Python")),Person("Sriram",List("Science","Maths","Hadoop","C2","c3")),Person("Jai",List("Flink","Scala","Haskell")))}

 val rdd=sc.parallelize(input)

 val mv=rdd.map(p=>(p.name,p.interest))

 val fmv=mv.flatMapValues(v=>v.toStream)

 fmv.collect
```

**Result is:**

```
  Array[(String, String)] = Array(
  (Chandru,Java), 
  (Chandru,Scala), 
  (Chandru,Python), 
  (Sriram,Science), 
  (Sriram,Maths), 
  (Sriram,Hadoop), 
  (Sriram,C2), 
  (Sriram,c3), 
  (Jai,Flink), 
  (Jai,Scala), 
  (Jai,Haskell))
```